# Enable/disable buttons with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, button

I'm making an web-app in angular 4. I use a property called currentLesson. This property has a variable number from 1 to 6.
In my component I have an list of 6 lessons where each lesson has it's own button to start this lesson.

In this list it should only be available to click the button when the currentLesson has the value of the number of the lesson:

Button of lesson 1 is active when : currentLesson = 1

Button of lesson 2 is active when : currentLesson = 2

Etc. etc.

So if currentLesson = 2, the buttons of lesson 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6 should be disabled.

I have the following set-up but it doesn't seem to work.
In my component i have:

```
export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
  classes = [
{
  name: 'string',
  level: 'string',
  code: 'number',
  currentLesson: '1'
}]



checkCurrentLesson1 = function(classes) {
if (classes.currentLesson = 1) { 
 return true;
}
else {
 return false;
}
};

checkCurrentLesson2 = function(classes) {
if (classes.currentLesson = 2) {
 return true;
}
else {
 return false;
}
};
```

And my html file is like this:

```
 <ul class="table lessonOverview">
    <li>
      <p>Lesson 1</p>
      <button [routerLink]="['/lesson1']" 
         [disabled]="!checkCurrentLesson1" class="primair">
           Start lesson</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Lesson 2</p>
      <button [routerLink]="['/lesson2']" 
         [disabled]="!checkCurrentLesson2" class="primair">
           Start lesson</button>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

(I only printed two of the six lessons, but they are all the same)

What's the solution?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Set a property for the current lesson: `currentLesson`. It will hold, obviously, the 'number' of the choosen lesson. On each button click, set the `currentLesson` value to 'number'/ order of the button, i.e. for the first button, it will be '1', for the second '2' and so on.
Each button now can be disabled with [disabled] attribute, if it the `currentLesson` is not the same as it's order.

**HTML**

```
  <button  (click)="currentLesson = '1'"
         [disabled]="currentLesson !== '1'" class="primair">
           Start lesson</button>
  <button (click)="currentLesson = '2'"
         [disabled]="currentLesson !== '2'" class="primair">
           Start lesson</button>
 .....//so on
```

**Typescript**

```
currentLesson:string;

  classes = [
{
  name: 'string',
  level: 'string',
  code: 'number',
  currentLesson: '1'
}]

constructor(){
  this.currentLesson=this.classes[0].currentLesson
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aenhkp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Putting everything in a loop:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let class of classes; let i = index">
   <button [disabled]="currentLesson !== i + 1" class="primair">
           Start lesson {{i +  1}}</button>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
currentLesson:string;

classes = [
{
  name: 'Lesson1',
  level: 1,
  code: 1,
},{
  name: 'Lesson2',
  level: 1,
  code: 2,
},
{
  name: 'Lesson3',
  level: 2,
  code: 3,
}]
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aenhkp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, clear as water now! 

I also have a question about setting the property 'currentLesson' + 1 when an other button is clicked in an other component, but maybe its the best that i'll make a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

my.component.html:

```
<button [disabled]="isSubmitBtnDisabled" (click)="addGame()">Send</button>
```

my.component.ts:

```
export class My implements OnInit {
  isSubmitBtnDisabled: boolean= false;

   private someMethodYouCalled() {
      this.isSubmitBtnDisabled = true;   //Controls if button is disabled
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
  classes = [
{
  name: 'string',
  level: 'string',
  code: 'number',
  currentLesson: '1'
}]


checkCurrentLession(current){

 this.classes.forEach((obj)=>{
    if(obj.currentLession == current){
      return true;
    }

  });
  return false;
}


<ul class="table lessonOverview">
        <li>
          <p>Lesson 1</p>
          <button [routerLink]="['/lesson1']" 
             [disabled]="checkCurrentLession(1)" class="primair">
               Start lesson</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Lesson 2</p>
          <button [routerLink]="['/lesson2']" 
             [disabled]="!checkCurrentLession(2)" class="primair">
               Start lesson</button>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p style="color: #28a745; font-weight: bold; font-size:25px; text-align: right " >Total Productos a pagar= {{ getTotal() }} {{ getResult() | currency }}
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!getResult()" (click)="onSubmit()">
        Ver Pedido
      </button>
     </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation as well. Only pasting a code block results in people copy-pasting the code without understanding it.